# Installing Cython/Statsmodels

Tags: python, cython, statsmodels

I can not for the life of me figure out how to install the package statsmodels for Python 3. It feels like I've tried everything, but nothing is working.

---

**Goal:** import statsmodels in python

I start with:

```
pip install statsmodels
```

Main error messages:

```
Failed bulding wheel for statsmodels.
Cython is required to compile statsmodels from a development branch.
Please install Cython or download a source release of statsmodels.
```

So I try:

```
pip install cython
```

Gives:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:users\XXX\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
```

---

I installed cython by installing anaconda. I have tried almost all answers I could find by basic googling. But things just don't seem to be working.

Instead of listing the input\output of what I have tried I now only show the first steps, but let me know if you want to see the output of any commands.

How do I continue from here? Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for several days now and I'm only getting frustrated.

---

Right now I'm trying:

```
easy_install cython
```

This seemed to work, but afterwards pip install statsmodels didn't work.

```
Command ... failed with error code 1.
```

I tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
cd statsmodels
pip install .
```

And failed with a bunch of errors.

Comment: Are you using a Unix-like OS or Windows? If not Windows, you might try `pip install statsmodels --only-binary=statsmodels` to force pip to install a wheel from the package index.

Otherwise, please post the errors you get from attempting to install from source?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am on Windows. When I tried your suggestion it gave me:

    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodels (from versions: )

    No matching distribution found for statsmodels

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem lastnight trying to install statsmodels. Finally what worked was installing the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266 then installing statsmodels by doing pip install statsmodels. I had already installed Cython by using pip. Though I do realize that was for Python 2.7. There doesn't seem to be this compiler available for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The main statsmodels on PyPI is very old and uses a nonstandard setup.  The release candidate for 0.10.0 is out now, and I would strongly recommend you use this one.  You can install it using

`pip install statsmodels=0.10.0rc2 --pre`

It has wheels for all of the major platforms (Win/OSX/Linux), so you shouldn't see issues related to Cython.

Answer (score 0):

To install statsmodels under anaconda, use

```
conda install statsmodels
```

The package is available in the [repository of anacondata](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/statsmodels) in version 0.8.0 which is the latest on pip as of now.

anaconda is not "just" a Python installation, it also contains the conda package manager that can install pre-built packages from the main repository of anaconda or from other "channels". It is not advisable to install packages that are available from the anaconda channel with pip, in general.

A comment on the issue of Cython here: to use Cython, your computer needs also a "development environment", that is the availability of a C compiler, of the Python development headers, among others. The C compiler must be compatible with the version of Python for which Cython is installed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

When I run this command it tells me "No module named 'pycosat'."
So I try to install pycosat:

    conda install -c anaconda pycosat   >>> No module named 'pycosat' /////
    pip3 install pycosat >>> Failed building wheels for pycosat.

To install this package, from googling I found out I need python-dev? But I can't seem to figure out how to install this either.


Any thoughts about this?

Comment: I can only guess that your anaconda install is broken: it cannot run the "conda" command and can thus not update itself. The "easy" reply for me is to advise you to remove and reinstall anaconda. You should also check whether you have conflicting installations of Python.